# Adding Labels and arrows in Tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to do something similar to this epsilon-delta graph I've found.  Specifically, I'd like to copy the placements and arrows, like the L+e and L-e coming out of L. Same thing with the x0 + d and x0-d coming out of the x0. Can someone help me with this? This is what I have so far. [image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
,
        legend pos=north east,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1},
        grid = major,
        width=8cm,  
        height=6cm,
        grid style={dashed, gray!30},
        xmin=0   ,     % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
        xmax= 4,    % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
        ymin= 0,     % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
        ymax= 11,   % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
%axis background/.style={fill=white},
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$f(x)$,
        tick align=outside,
        enlargelimits=false]
% plot the stirling-formulae
%\addplot[domain=0:200, red, ultra thick,samples=100] {K/(1 +    ((K-X0)/X0) * exp(r*x))    };
\addplot[domain=0:200, red, ultra thick,samples=100] {3*x-1 };

\addplot[line width=1pt, dashed, mark=none, black] coordinates {(0,8) (3,8)};
\addplot[line width=1pt, dashed, mark=none, black] coordinates {(3,0) (3,8)};
\addplot[line width=1pt, dashed, mark=none, blue] coordinates {(3.33,0) (3.333,9)};
\addplot[line width=1pt, dashed, mark=none, blue] coordinates {(2.666,7) (2.666,0)};
\addplot[line width=1pt, dashed, mark=none, blue] coordinates {(2.666,7) (0,7)};
\addplot[line width=1pt, solid, mark=none, blue] coordinates {(3.333,9) (0,9)};
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(60,8.66)};

% 1\addlegendentry{$f(x) = 10 \sin (x)$}

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives[image]

Comment: no, I'm using the same account. I made a similar post a couple days ago before I really worked on it. Now I've worked on it and I'm genuinely stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `pgfplots` is a bit of an overkill for a cartoon.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[holdot/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=1pt}]
 \draw[line width=4mm,blue!30] (3,0)--(3,4);
 \draw[very thick,red!80!pink,dashed] (2.8,0) -- (2.8,4);
 \draw[double distance=4mm,very thick,double=orange,red!80!pink] (0,4) -- (5,4);
 \draw[very thick,red!80!pink,dashed] (3.2,0) -- (3.2,4.2);
 \draw[thick,-latex] (-2,0) -- (6,0);
 \draw[thick,-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6);
 \draw[very thick,blue!50!cyan] (-0.8,0.2) -- (3.5,4.5) to[out=45,in=135] 
 node[pos=0.5,above,font=\large]{$y=f(x)$} (5,4.5);
 \draw[very thick,dashed] (0,4) node[left] (L) {$L$} -| (3,0) node[below] (x0) {$x_0$};
 \draw[very thick,blue!50!cyan,fill=white] (3,4) circle[radius=2pt];
 \draw (L) -- ++(120:0.7) node[above] {$L+\varepsilon$}
 (L) -- ++(-120:0.7) node[below] {$L-\varepsilon$}
 (x0) -- ++(-45:0.7) node[below right] {$x_0+\delta$}
 (x0) -- ++(-135:0.7) node[below left] {$x_0-\delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the pureness

Comment: @JouleV Or poorness? ;-)

Comment: If it was 'poorness' the plus sign would be a minus sign :)

Comment: @JouleV It is almost Easter and I once learned one should give to the poor... ;-)

Comment: One should always give things to the poor who don't have enough money, and should always give downvotes to the poor who don't have good contents. You are certainly none of these 'poor's.

Comment: @JouleV I leave the downvote business to others. The only ones which I sometimes feel I want to downvote are the ones who "steal" from others, but then I remind myself that what they want most is attention, and by not downvoting them I deny them this attention.... ;-)